# Copy a specific table from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of our staff members made a change on the live DB that has wiped the address details of circa 3000 users. I have attached yesterdays backup to a new DB, meaning I have a table of all the correct address on a different database.

Is there an easy way I can essentially copy this table from the backup DB to the live DB? I will of course test it first, as I wish this user did. I don't want to restore from the backup is it will erase a lot in different tables.

I have attached a backup of the DB in order to extract the records needed.

I probably should've added this, but the entire table hasn't been erased, just a number of records within the table. The table itself has
SerialNum, FirstName, LastName, Address 1, PostCode etc
The SerialNum, FirstName, LastName are all still fine, it's just the address fields that have been erased through a bad data import

Comment: What's wrong with an `INSERT...SELECT`?

Comment: I've *assumed* you are actually using SQL Server here, however, if you are using a different product that you can connect to using SSMS, such as Azure SQL Database, please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: Restore the backup on the same server (as a different db name), then update Db1 from your Db2 restore table, something like: `UPDATE A SET Address = B.Address FROM Db1.dbo.Table A JOIN Db2.dbo.Table B ON A.UserID = B.UserID WHERE ...`

Comment: Write a `select` query to select from your restored DB table where rows do `not exists` in the target table; check this data is correct, then change it to an `insert`; then enjoy a coffee.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ProdDB.dbo.[TableName]
SELECT *
FROM RestoredDB.dbo.[TableName] r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProdDB.dbo.[TableName] p WHERE p.ID = r.ID)
```

Of course you'll need to adjust that based on the real primary key and name of the table, and you may also need to turn on [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: I probably should've added this, but the entire table hasn't been erased, just a number of records within the table. Will the insert command work if record exists?

The table itself has

SerialNum, FirstName, LastName, Address 1, PostCode etc 

The SerialNum, FirstName, LastName are all still fine. It's just the Address fields that have been erased through a very bad attempt at a data import on our CRM which I am trying to rectify in ssms

Comment: @AdamT312 Your question is becoming even more unclear and you seem to be confusing the meaning of records, columns, fields, rows, data etc. IF you don't mean that *rows* have been deleted (which is kinda what everyone reading your question has assumed) then presumably you just need to inner join your original and restored tables and *update* the relevant *columns*.

Comment: @AdamT312 You need to clean up your terminology. If you say certain records within a table are gone, that tells us _the entire rowr_ are gone, not just field data within the rows. I know it sounds pedantic, but computers are the ultimate pedants, and so in this field getting this stuff right is important. It's like telling us the alternator doesn't work in your car, when the problem is actually the transmission. Fine for a layperson, but alarming if you claim to be a mechanic.